# Renewing Spring managed singleton bean dependency in thread safe fashion

Tags: java, spring, thread-safety, inversion-of-control, synchronized

I have a Spring managed singleton bean that requires to renew its dependency based on a certain condition:

```
@Component
public class BeanClass {

    private DependencyClass dependency;

    public void beanMethod() {
        // if dependency is not initialised or otherwise requires renewal (becomes stale)
        if (condition) {
            dependency = renewDependency();
        }
        // use dependency
    }
}
```

This `bean` is used in highly multithreaded environment and I'd like to ensure that while `dependency` is being renewed in one thread (could be an expensive process) no other thread can use `dependency` or enter renewal condition logic again.

I understand I have few options I should either use some of them or few of them in combination:

- add `volatile` modifier to `dependency`. My understanding this is just a hint to a compiler and doesn't solve a problem on its own?
- wrap `if (condition)` with `synchronized`. What do I use as a lock object? `dependency` itself, `this` or `private final Object lock = new Object()` class field?
- extract `if (condition)` into a method and put `synchronized` on it instead. Is it the same as `synchronized(this)` option above?

What is the preferred way to achieve this task?

I wonder if there is any magic in Spring's IoC container, proxying, or anything that could simplify this for me.

Comment: When `dependency` is not being renewed, are multiple threads allowed to use it at the same time?

Comment: yeah, absolutely

Comment: Do you know the maximum number of threads that can be spawned by your application (or the size of the thread pool)?

Comment: @takanuva15 it's highly dynamic environment, not sure. Why would it matter?